# How can I export a two-way table?

Tags: stata

I have created a two-way summary table in Stata, but I am struggling to output my results.

Using the `auto.dta` sample dataset as an example, I am trying to build a table that displays the means and standard deviations of `mpg`, by two other variables (`expensive` and `foreign`).

My code currently looks as follows:

```
sysuse auto.dta, replace
gen expensive = (price > 5000)
```

The table that I would like to display can be created by either of the two commands below:

```
tabulate expensive foreign, sum(mpg)

       Means, Standard Deviations and Frequencies of Mileage (mpg)

           |      Car type
 expensive |  Domestic    Foreign |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         0 | 22.137931     28.875 | 23.594595
           | 4.3648281  4.8825491 | 5.2305696
           |        29          8 |        37
-----------+----------------------+----------
         1 | 16.913043  22.428571 |        19
           | 3.4629604  6.4416229 | 5.4467115
           |        23         14 |        37
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total | 19.826923  24.772727 | 21.297297
           | 4.7432972  6.6111869 | 5.7855032
           |        52         22 |        74
```

```
table expensive foreign, c(mean mpg sd mpg) row col

    ----------------------------------------
              |           Car type          
    expensive | Domestic   Foreign     Total
    ----------+-----------------------------
            0 |  22.1379    28.875   23.5946
              | 4.364828  4.882549   5.23057
              |       29         8        37
              | 
            1 |   16.913   22.4286        19
              |  3.46296  6.441623  5.446712
              |       23        14        37
              | 
        Total |  19.8269   24.7727   21.2973
              | 4.743297  6.611187  5.785503
              |       52        22        74
    ----------------------------------------
```

I can also closely approximate the same results using `collapse`, but this does not calculate row and column totals.

My issue is that neither the `tabulate` (with the `sum` option) command nor the `table` command seem friendly to output.  I have tried converting to matrices, but `tabulate` with the `sum` option does not allow the `matcell` option and `table` seems similarly uncooperative.

I'm familiar with `tabstat`, `esttab` etc., but was not able to create the two-way table that I need with any of those packages.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The *community-contributed* command `asdoc` does exactly that:

```
. asdoc table expensive foreign, c(mean mpg sd mpg count mpg) row col

----------------------------------------
          |           Car type          
expensive | Domestic   Foreign     Total
----------+-----------------------------
        0 |  22.1379    28.875   23.5946
          | 4.364828  4.882549   5.23057
          |       29         8        37
          | 
        1 |   16.913   22.4286        19
          |  3.46296  6.441623  5.446712
          |       23        14        37
          | 
    Total |  19.8269   24.7727   21.2973
          | 4.743297  6.611187  5.785503
          |       52        22        74
----------------------------------------
Click to Open File:  Myfile.doc
```

Alternatively, one could use the *community-contributed* command `tabout`:

```
. tabout expensive foreign using table1.txt, c(mean mpg) sum replace

Table output written to: table1.txt

        Car type
        Domestic        Foreign Total
        Mean mpg        Mean mpg        Mean mpg
expensive
0       22.1    28.9    23.6
1       16.9    22.4    19.0
Total   19.8    24.8    21.3
```

```
. tabout expensive foreign using table2.txt, c(sd mpg) sum replace

Table output written to: table2.txt

        Car type
        Domestic        Foreign Total
        Sd mpg  Sd mpg  Sd mpg
expensive
0       4.4     4.9     5.2
1       3.5     6.4     5.4
Total   4.7     6.6     5.8
```

```
. tabout expensive foreign using table3.txt, c(count mpg) sum replace

Table output written to: table3.txt  

        Car type
        Domestic        Foreign Total
        Count mpg       Count mpg       Count mpg
expensive
0       29.0    8.0     37.0
1       23.0    14.0    37.0
Total   52.0    22.0    74.0
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy solution is to use `collapse` to get a dataset that reproduces your desired table, and then export the dataset as a `csv`

example

`collapse (sum) mpg, by(expensive foreign)`

and then

`export delimited using mydata.csv`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Noobie.  Unfortunately `collapse `doesn't give me the row/column totals that I'd like.  For instance, collapse will display the mean mpg when expensive = 0 and foreign = 0, when expensive = 0 and foreign = 1....etc.  It will fill in each of the 4 cells; it won't provide the overall mpg when expensive = 0.  Both examples that I give, using `tabulate` and `table`, give row and column totals like I want, but aren't easily output...  If you can show me a way to get row and column totals using `collapse`, that would be fantastic.

Comment: The idea of storing totals with the dataset as extra observations is alien to Stata, but you can add extra variables using `egen`'s `total()` function.

Comment: Hi Nick.  I appreciate the suggestion.  The `egen total` function will allow me to sum across by groups, and I could also use `egen mean` to calculate the equally weighted average over the collapsed dataset.  Neither of these is what I'm trying to accomplish.  I want the average mpg across all observations where expensive = 0 (and separately, where expensive = 1).  Compare the output of `tab expensive foreign, sum(mpg)` to a collapsed dataset.  I'm a bit skeptical that `collapse` is going to work at all.  Is there a way to simply output the table that results from that `tabulate` command?

Comment: You can use `egen`'s `mean()` and `by(expensive)` to calculate such means.  Stata doesn't naturally support the kind of data structure I think you seek; it really has no interest in trying to be a spreadsheet program. Whatever would be marginal information in a table can not easily be added to the dataset in any form other than as extra variables. Those who live by the sword, die by the sword. If you are interested in using an Excel file for output, why not compute the extra information in Excel? (Sorry, I really have no advice on how you would do it.)

Comment: Note that `collapse` as specified in this answer does not produce anything even remotely near what the OP asks (i.e. what `tabulate` and `table` produce).